# Excluding files based on parent directory in RubCop

Tags: rubocop

I've been scratching my head a bit on how to exclude files based on the name of one of the parent directories. I'm not sure if this is something that's not possible or if I'm just missing some real obvious syntax here.

I have a cop that's examining large repositories where I don't control the exact directory structure. I need to skip examining files in any directory named `test` though no matter where it occurs in the directory structure. For instance `my-repo/foo/bar/test/foo/bar/file.rb` should not be examined and `my-repo/test/another_file.rb` should also not be examined. Is there any way to define an exclude that's basically `'**/test/**/*.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. You can find an example in e.g. [in `rubocop-rspec` extension](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rspec/blob/7cf850deaf1c7d85b41cef1802106e4ec31193bd/config/default.yml#L6):

```yaml
  Include:
    - "**/spec/**/*"
```

It would work the same way with `Exclude`.
It works both for `AllCops`, and specific cops can be configured as well.